# Onto but not one-to-one solution of Cauchy's functional equation (C.F.E)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Does anyone knows some facts about functional equations? I've been a long time thinking about this question: "Show that there exists a function verifying C.F.E., wich is onto but not one-to-one."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ be  a Hamel basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$. Then the indexing set $I$ has cardinality same as that of $\mathbb R$. Let $i_0 \in I$ be fixed and consider a bijection $h: I\setminus \{i_o\}$ to $\mathbb R$. Define $f(x_i)=h(i)$ for $i \neq i_0$ and define $f(x_{i_0})$ arbitrarily. This $f$ extends to an additive function from $\mathbb R$ into itself. It is clear that this is onto but not one-to-one . (Note that $f(x_{i_0})$ is already included in $\{f(x_i): i \neq i_0\}$).